# create file in a folder in c++ programming

Tags: c++, file-handling

how to create file in a folder c programming?

i have a program which it will get id number and make it as a filename, i want to save that file into a specific folder but it always make filename as "id".
sample:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {   FILE *filehandling;
    char inputA, name[20], birthday[20], gender[6], add[50], contact[15], id[15];
        cout<<"Name\t\t   : ";
        gets(name);
        cout<<"Birthday mm/dd/yy  : ";
        cin>>birthday;
        cout<<"Gender\t\t   : ";
        cin>>gender;
        cout<<"I.D #\t\t   : ";
        cin>>id;
        cout<<"Contact #\t   : ";
        cin>>contact;
        cout<<"Address\t\t   : ";
        gets(add);

    filehandling = fopen(id,"a");
    fprintf(filehandling, "Name\t   : %s\n", name);
    fprintf(filehandling, "Birthday   : %s\n", birthday);
    fprintf(filehandling, "Gender\t   : %s\n", gender);
    fprintf(filehandling, "I.D #\t   : %s\n", id);
    fprintf(filehandling, "Contact #  : %s\n", contact);
    fprintf(filehandling, "Address\t   : %s\n", add);
    fclose(filehandling);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `fopen()` in C++?

Comment: This code sort of looks more like C++ than C.  Are you sure you are trying to create a file in a folder in C programming?

Comment: Why are you using `gets()` at all? It has never been safe, and has been removed from recent versions of the C standard.

Comment: Where does the program specify the folder to create the file in?

Comment: Use `std::string` and then concatenate the folder name with `id` to create the pathname to the file in the folder.

Comment: C++ sorry i'm kinda confuse right now hahaha. actually i have a directory of D:\\try\\ where the program is located then i want to save files to D:\\try\\FILES\\.

Comment: I highly recommend not *crossing the streams*.  Use either C++ streams (`std::cout, std::fstream`) or C streams (`scanf, fprintf`).  Don't mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand fully your question..

but.. why don't you make a folder ??

make a folder, write a file inside there.

```
...
char folder_name[ MAX_PATH ];
sprintf( folder_name, "c:\\folder\\%s", folder_for_id );
mkdir( folder_name );
char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
sprintf( filename, "%s\\%s", folder_name, id );
FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "wt" );
...
```

Comment: wait i will this one. i am currently making a file handling where i need to store date into a file with a file name of what i have inputted to the id umber. then i need to store those files to a specific folder and not to the folder where i have saved the program.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @JimColinPeña To create a file inside specific folder, you should use full path when write the file. If the specific folder doesnot exist, create the folder first.. You can use my code to code these.

Comment: yeah i already used your code and i works. thank you very much. i owe you for this.

Comment: Also useful: [C++ File System Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs). Specifically [`create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory).

Comment: @JimColinPeña you owe him an upvote and to accept the answer, nothing more ;)